# Maven/Jacoco - after succesful tests and jacoco datafiles merge, how to get a merged report?

Tags: maven-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

For a Maven multi module project, running unit and/or integration tests with code Coverage Jacoco **work fine**. Merging the Jacoco code coverage results in 1 datafile works! So, this is **not a duplicate question**.

Based on that correctly merge Jacoco datafile, how can I get an **overall report**?

**UPDATE**: after scanning all solutions, a lot of trial and error, I created a simple project that satisfied all requirements, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to create a simple but complete **Jacoco** demo project showing. It a simple but complete solution, also using the combined Jacoco datafile and an aggregate report!

- Multi module project
- Unit test (via mvn clean install)
- Integration test (via mvn clean install -P integration-test)
- Jacoco - test coverage ( both aggregate datafile and aggregate reporting)
- FindBugs - code quality

Enjoy the [sipmle demo project](https://github.com/johan974/maven-multi-module-unittest-integrationtest-jacoco.git).